# saving a float value in a string variable

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to divide two numbers fetched from edit text and save it in a `TextView` but I am unable to save a float type `Number` into `String`

```
tv.setData(div.toString()); //not working
```

In this code, where `tv` is `TextView` type variable and `div` is float type variable.

Comment: Did you try setData(div)? if not, do (new Float(div)).toString()

Comment: `String.valueOf(div)`

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: used double,instead of float and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.valueOf(div)` instead of `div.toString()` like so:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(div));
```